# Union of an open set with a boundary point

Tags: general-topology

Let S be the union of  E = {$x^2 + y^2 < 1$}  and the point P = {(0, 1)}.
Is the set S open or closed or neither of them?

I know it should be trivial but I'm not sure about the answer.
I would say it is closed, since the point P is on the boundary but belongs to the set, hence the definition "set D is open if every point of D is an interior point of D" does not apply.
However I don't think it makes much sense.

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: From the statement "set $D$ is open if every point of $D$ is an interior point of $D$" you can deduce that your set is **not** open, but being not open does not imply being closed. You need to check that separately (Are all boundary points of $E$ part of $E$?)

Comment: Oh ok thank you, I see

Comment: By the way, the way to type sets in math mode is with `\{...\}`. Eg $\{(x,y):x^2+y^2=1\}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not open as $P$, a boundary point is **not** in the interior.

It's not closed as $(0,-1)$, another boundary point, is not in the set.

So "neither" is correct. If we would have added **all** boundary points of $E$ result would have been closed. Adding just one doesn't do it.